# How do i use CASE in mysql select query with left join?

Tags: php, mysql

```
select  r.email,
        rc.cuisine_id,
        rc.restaurant_id, 
        c.id as c_id ,
        c.name as cus_name,
        r.image,
        r.web_address,
        r.area,
        rp.TypeId,  
        rp.PaymentStatus , 
        rp.RestaurantId 
from restaurant as r
left join restaurant_cuisine as rc on r.id=rc.restaurant_id
left join cuisine as c on rc.cuisine_id=c.id  where c.status='1'
```

Case statement that is needed

```
CASE WHEN rp.TypeId = '1' 
     THEN left join restaurant_payment as rp on r.id=rp.RestaurantId 
     WHEN rp.TypeId = '3'
     THEN left join users as u on rp.RestaurantId=u.id
END
```

Comment: why can't have the condition in the join itself. left join restaurant_payment as rp on r.id=rp.RestaurantId and rp.TypeId ='1'
left join users as u on rp.RestaurantId=u.id and rp.TypeId ='3'

Comment: This may be dumb question but why not have two queries in your programming logic?

Comment: @Bharath, just append my query statement in the comment to your query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  r.email,
        rc.cuisine_id,
        rc.restaurant_id, 
        c.id as c_id ,
        c.name as cus_name,
        r.image,
        r.web_address,
        r.area,
        rp.TypeId,  
        rp.PaymentStatus , 
        rp.RestaurantId 
from restaurant as r
left join restaurant_cuisine as rc on r.id=rc.restaurant_id
left join cuisine as c on rc.cuisine_id=c.id  where c.status='1' and
rp.TypeId = CASE 
                 WHEN rp.TypeId = '1' 
                 THEN left join restaurant_payment as rp on r.id=rp.RestaurantId 
                 WHEN rp.TypeId = '3'
                 THEN left join users as u on rp.RestaurantId=u.id
            END
```